# Publishing in Expo, dependancy hell

Tags: expo

I am getting these two errors in my Expo IDE:

Warning: You are using npm version 5.6.0. There may be bugs in this version, use it at your own risk. We recommend version 4.6.1.

Warning: Expo version in package.json does not match sdkVersion in manifest.

Warning: 'react' peer dependency missing. Run `npm ls` in C:\users\matt\sites\rg-calendar to see full warning.
If there is an issue running your project, please run `npm install` in C:\users\matt\sites\rg-calendar and restart.

Whn I run `npm ls` I have a load of missing packages, I the run `npm install` but I just get unmet dependancy errors.

My app.json file is:

```
{
  "expo": {
   "name": "RGUC",
   "icon": "./img/calendarIcon.png",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "slug": "rguc-calendar",
   "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
   "ios": {
     "bundleIdentifier": "com.rguc.calendar"
   },
   "android": {
     "package": "com.rguc.calendar"
   }
  }
}
```

I have the same `react-native` version in my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rgcalendar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.69.0",
    "jest-expo": "21.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.8.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "lint": "eslint --fix *.js",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^21.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.16.1",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.3",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^1.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I am using NVM:

```
    9.5.0
  * 8.10.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    6.11.1
    4.6.1
    4.4.0
```

How can I publish my expo project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downgrading NPM use this command: `npm install -g npm@4` it will install 4.6.1 (at this moment).

The current Expo version is 26. Expo 21 is based on react-native 0.48 and that on react 16.0.0 So maybe you have some modules which are not compatible with that versions anymore.

For the unmet dependencies try the following: remove (or move) the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install again` also try `npm cache clean`.

Maybe [upgrading your react versions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) also solves the issues.

Finally for publishing, you could [install the Expo XDE](https://expo.io/tools#xde) which makes it much easier. Of course first you must get rid of any compile errors (not the warnings) before beeing able to publish your Expo project.

Answer (score 0):

With my experience, I can say that npm version 5.6.0 is buggy. Use npm 4.6.1, its fully stable. You can do it by `npm uninstall npm@5.6.0 && npm install npm@4.6.1`. After that, do `npm -v` to see if 4.6.1 is displayed or its still 5.6.0. If this works, you will see 4.6.1 instead of 5.6.0. Let me know if this fixes your issue.

For publishing your Expo project, simply follow the steps from this link as it is -> https://docs.expo.io/versions/v19.0.0/workflow/building-standalone-apps